# Python Metaclass __new__ method not getting called

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading, metaclass

Based on my limited Python knowledge Metaclass is another class. In the following example I am just building a metaclass. Here I overloaded the `__new__` method. My expectation is at the end of the class declaration when `type.__new__()`
is called it will be delegated to `MyMeta.__new__()`. But that never happens.

```
print('Building MetaOne')

class MyMeta(type):
      def __new__(meta, classname, supers, classdict):
          print('In MyMeta:', classname)

      def myfunc(self):
          print ('In myfunc')
```

Here from `MyMeta`'s `__new__()` I don't see the print.

But on the contrary if I now use `MyMeta` class as a meta class to another class like:

```
print('Building Another class')
class Super(metaclass = MyMeta):
      def myfunc(self):
          print ('In Super myfunc')
```

At the end of this class I see MyMeta's `__new__` is getting invoked.

Can some one please help me understand why this happens?

Comment: No, `__new__` is not called when you created the meta class; . `Super` is an *instance* of the metatype, a class object, so then `__new__` is called to create it. Note that your `__new__` method returns `None`, rather than a new class object. You may want to add `return super().__new__(meta, classname, supers, classdict)` to the end of it.

Comment: You can use `__new__` on a class definition as well, and it would only be called when you call the class to create new instances.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Is this because when I create class object MyMeta (or any other class object), only the \__new()__ function of it's metaclass  or metaclass of the base classes get called ?

Comment: exactly, which is `type()`. You can't create meta metaclasses.